# Suppressing the “Picked up _JAVA_OPTIONS” when calling scala script from bash script

Tags: bash, scala

I am calling Scala script from bash. I set environment variables in my bash script like this:

```
export _JAVA_OPTIONS="-Xmx4g"
```

before calling Scala script.

When I ran my bash script it displays message

```
Picked up _JAVA_OPTIONS: -Xmx4g
Picked up _JAVA_OPTIONS: -Xmx4g
warning : there was one feature warning; re-run with -feature for details
```

then called Scala script. Program is running fine. but i want to suppress these messages.

Comment: I researched on on similar thread in stackoverflow but it did not help me out.

Comment: You want to suppress which messages? The warning or the "Picked up" messages or both? Does your script have other output you *do* care about?

Comment: I want to suppress both of the message. yes there is other output too and i need that. Thk u.

Comment: I assume those come from the scala script and not your bash script? I also assume you need other output from the scala script and not just other output from your bash script? If that's true then you'll need to pipe the output from your scala script to `sed` or `awk` or something similar and suppress printing for those lines you don't want. (Or edit the scala script/etc. to not print them in the first place.)

Comment: I need output from bash script and scala script printed on bash screen. The message appears due to this line just after that     export _JAVA_OPTIONS="-Xmx4g"

Comment: my code looks like this:  export _JAVA_OPTIONS="-Xmx4g"
    export CLASSPATH=$CLASSPATH:/usr/share/java/sqlite-jdbc-3.8.10.1.jar  # this line below calls scala script
    call_script "bin/metadata3_compare $medataData3File1  $medataData3File2 ${log_path}"

Comment: Then you get to edit the scala script to stop it doing that or filter the output (with `sed`/`awk`/etc.) to avoid printing the lines you don't want to see.

Comment: you are right. i get this message as soon as i call scala script. But i don't know to how suppress this message. it is getting printed automatically.

Comment: That's something the scala script is doing (or scala itself is doing). If you can't edit the script then you can't stop it that way and you get to filter the output as I've suggested.

Answer (score 0):

thanks to Etan Reisner. I solved it. My scala script looked like this  before:

exec scala "$0" "$@" 
!#
import java.io.PrintWriter
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat

after change: it looks like this 
exec scala "$0" "$@" 2> /dev/null  ( My changes here in this line) 
!#
import java.io.PrintWriter
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat

I just redirected error in 1st line like this in bash scala script: 
exec scala "$0" "$@" 2> /dev/null